# Mobile Website for Iphone

Tags: iphone, mobile, web

I want to know if it is possible to make a mobile website and store it in my iPhone. My iPhone would be the localhost. If it is possible, do I need to use any specific web technology for that?

As it is for now, what I want to do is pretty simple, I want the user to input a value, then the website would generate a certain number of forms based on the input of the user.

Comment: depends on what you mean by 'store' it in your phone. You can create an app with a single view, set that view with a web view, and then you can just set the url of your website in the web view as a way of storing it. You would possibly need javascript, php, or even something similar for the way you want to accept the user input

Comment: When I mean store, what I want is to put the website in the device so I can play around without the need of internet. The concept would be the same as developing a website on your computer and then be able to see how it works without the need of internet.

Comment: maybe you can try CocoaHTTPServer https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer

Answer (score 0):

Download the Adobe edge inspect app on your phone http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/ and download the Adobe edge inspect extension on your browser, everything you need to get running is on the website above. Thats what I'm using to test my site locally on the iPhone. Just use the trial version if your not already using the cloud services.